# Convergence of expression involving multiple series with given conditions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n),(b_n)$ be real sequences such that $b_n\gt 0\; \forall n$, $a_n\to L$, and $\sum b_n$ diverges.

(1) Prove $\sum b_n \to \infty$

(2) Prove $\large\frac{\sum a_nb_n}{\sum b_n}\to L$

I have completed (1) as it follows nicely from noting that the sequence is increasing, but I am stuck on (2). I have an idea to show something like
$$\lvert\sum^n a_ib_i-L\sum^n b_i\rvert\leq \epsilon\sum^n b_i$$
for given $\epsilon$ and $n\geq N$ for some $N$, which would then give the result immediately but I am unsure how to show this. I know I can bound the difference between $a_n$ and $L$ for a given $N$ but I don't see how to bound the starting terms. A hint would be great!

Comment: At first glance 2 doesn’t look true at all. Let $a_n = 1$ $\forall n$, $b_n = n$ $\forall n$. Then the sum in 2 diverges. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: there's a typo in (2): it should be $b_i$ in the denominator instead of $a_i$.

Comment: Hint: write $\sum a_ib_i-L\sum b_i=\sum(a_i-L)b_i=I+II,$ where I is the sum for small i and II is the sum for large i. in II you have $|a_i-L|<\epsilon$, while for some reason I doesn't matter beause it's smaller, or has only a certain number of terms or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've corrected the typo and you actually want just a hint on the starting terms: Fix $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N$ so $|a_i-L|<\epsilon$ for $i>N$ (so we've handled the sum from $N$ to $n$.) Say $$k=\max_{1\le j\le N}|a_j-L|.$$**Since** $ \sum b_j$ diverges we have $$\sum_{j=1}^Nb_j<\frac\epsilon k\sum_{j=1}^n b_j$$for large enough $n$. That handles the starting terms, I think maybe...